# Migración de datos de Struts 1.0.3 (1.x) a Struts 2.5.18 (2.5.x)

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, struts

Tengo un proyecto con páginas jsp. Apenas hay información en internet sobre migrar ficheros de Struts 1.0 a Struts 2.5. El entorno de desarrollo que utilizo es Netbeans, conexión a servidor Glassfish 4.0 de Oracle.  La pregunta es:
qué ficheros hay que modificar, por ejemplo, el web.xml, el strutts.xml, etc. En estos ficheros vienen el filter y el servlet. Sé que el controller a partir del 2.0 es el Dispatcher.

Paso este enlace como "ejemplo" de pasar ficheros de Struts 1.0 a Struts 2.0 (pero claro, puede conllevar cambios nuevos de cara a la versión 2.5 de Struts).
Enlace: http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/struts-2010-11/sesion04-struts-apuntes.html

Si alguien sabe una solución alternativa, será bienvenida.

Gracias por adelantado,

Comment: Disculpa mi curiosidad: ¿Por qué pasar de Struts 1 (totalmente obsoleto y sin mantenimiento) a Struts2 (aún tiene mantenimiento, pero también obsoleto)? Me parece un gran esfuerzo (son dos frameworks totalmente distintos, no se reutilizó casi nada de Struts1 al implementar Struts2) de migración para seguir estando *anticuado*

Comment: Sin problema te respondo, el cambio de versión de Struts es para adaptarlo a una versión más reciente de IBM Sterling, una herramienta empresarial que uso y que influye en el proyecto. El Struts 1 es de hace años y se ha ido quedando como bien dices anticuado. Me comentan que una idea es hacer de cero todo  en lugar de migración, crear un proyecto directamente en Struts 2 con sus objetos (clases, métodos, jsp, etc.) de cero, porque comparando las clases java y jsp disponibles. Por ahora, como me comentó Mikel, me pongo con las librerías, me las acaban de pasar.

Comment: Si vas a hacerlo de cero te recomiendo usar Spring web en lugar de Struts2. Los JSP están cada vez más en desuso, pero al menos con Spring podrías migrar más tarde a otra tecnología con más facilidad (mucha más documentación y preguntas/respuestas en SO)

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127369/migration-from-struts-1-to-struts-2) a la misma pregunta en stackOverflow a la que respondieron con bastantes enlaces útiles, y de paso este pequeño [manual](https://dzone.com/articles/struts-migration-strategies) que te ayudara a planificar la estrategia a seguir.

Struts de por si es bastante enrevesado, y los cambios entre versiones son considerables, así que paciencia y mucha suerte!

Comment: El problema es que hay algunas clases en nuestro proyecto que no existen, como la clase Action, o etiquetas que figura la versión 1 de Struts, creo que la mejor opción es hablar con los desarrolladores del proyecto que me aclaren qué hay que modificar, aparte del manual que me has pasado.  Gracias Mikel por tu respuesta.

Comment: Por curiosidad, como es que no existen estas clases? Quiero decir, en un proyecto Struts las action class son pilares fundamentales para la lógica de negocio

Comment: Te explico, al configurar el servidor Glassfish de Oracle, me pregunta qué framework usar, elijo Struts, y al importar el proyecto se generan unos import y se marcan subrayados en rojo, leyendo los hints de Netbeans dice que falta la clase, el Action por ejemplo no existe en ese proyecto, el login esta diferente a cómo está explicado en la guía, por eso te comento de hablar con los desarrolladores, si me lo pueden aclarar

Comment: Adjunto imagen:  http://i63.tinypic.com/1snspu.png

Comment: Este error apunta a que falta algún *.jar por incluir o que el classpath para este no esta bien definido. Yo empezaría mirando el struts core.jar.  Seguramente los desarrolladores te puedan ayudar más teniendo delante, un saludo!

Comment: Exacto, sí, faltan los .jar de las librerías. Gracias de nuevo, un saludo.